# GridDB - Where to get gridstore.jar file

Tags: griddb

I am trying to work on GridDB with Java. I am following the guide here: https://griddb.net/en/blog/using-maven-to-develop-griddb-applications/

The script shows that I would need a JAR file called gridstore.jar but I am not sure where to get it. I tried using the maven dependency which is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.griddb</groupId>
<artifactId>gridstore</artifactId>
<version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't work. Where could I get this gridstore.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the jar files from here. This is the latest version:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.griddb/gridstore-jdbc/5.3.0